# Google colab upload time to google drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, zip, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using google colab to extract data from a zip file I have stored on the colab drive. I mounted my google drive to the colab workspace and used the following code to unzip the data to the google drive:

```
!unzip '/content/g2net-gravitational-wave-detection.zip' -d '/content/drive/MyDrive/'
```

This took about 6/7 hours to run as there is about 80gb of data to extract.

I have read online that when using colab, although it extracts items to the mounted google drive, it first extracts them to colab and then after completion it uploads them to the actual google drive.

My question is regarding the upload; I have checked and all my data has successfully extracted to the colab drive and is clearly currently moving accross to google drive now; but only about 10gb of it so far. I was just wondering if there is any way to see how fast this is transferring/ how much is transferred. Just that I only have a pro subscription so I think if I idle too long or close the session I will lose all of the extracted data.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!